Why did God rest on the seventh day?
Why did God rest on the seventh day?
Resting on the seventh day is from the biblical creation story in Genesis. After creating the world in six days, God rested on the seventh, which is seen as a model for humans to follow—a rhythm of work and rest. It's not so much about God needing a break, but about teaching the importance of rest and reflection.

I don't see a question being asked here...

Why does God rest on the seventh day, sounds like a question in the most literal sense.

Despite my answer, someone needs to edit the title. Why does God rest on the 7th day of creation, would be a better title then "resting of Jesus"

@Wyrsa, I've changed the question (I think you could have made the change and submitted it as a suggestion). It's possible my changing "does" into "did" has changed the original intent of the question (in which case Faz should let me know), but it now matches the current answers.

@Wyrsa, but the remainder of the "question" answers that. It's not unusual for us to get "questions" that are really just "preaching" / someone using the SE to disseminate some belief or claim of their own. This, as it stands, looks (to me at least) like one of those.

Welcome to C.SE.  It appears you are simply posting BOTH question and answer in your post.  This is not how the site works.  Please edit your question to remove the answer (the 2nd paragraph) and transfer it to your own answer (because in an SE site you can answer your own question).  But the Q needs to be better than simply asking "Why did God rest on the seventh day", so please add more details on what you are asking.

I think the confusion that caused your question is based on a misunderstanding of the word "rest".

What do you mean by "rest" ? It can be an action, inaction, or even a state of being.
Inaction: I rested, could mean I slept or "chilled" in the living room. Etc.
Action: The Bread dough rests. It is highly active and changing shape etc.
State of being: The truck came to a rest at the side of the road".
State of being 2: The king rests on his throne, looking over his kingdom.

Well, what is the scripture in question?

Thus the heavens and the earth, and all the host of them, were finished. 2 And on the seventh day God ended His work which He had done, and He rested on the seventh day from all His work which He had done. 3 Then God blessed the seventh day and sanctified it, because in it He rested from all His work which God had created and made. (Genesis 2:1-3 NKJV)


וַיְכֻלּוּ הַשָּׁמַיִם וְהָאָרֶץ, וְכָל-צְבָאָם.
וַיְכַל אֱלֹהִים בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי, מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה; וַיִּשְׁבֹּת בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי, מִכָּל-מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה.
וַיְבָרֶךְ אֱלֹהִים אֶת-יוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי, וַיְקַדֵּשׁ אֹתוֹ:  כִּי בוֹ שָׁבַת מִכָּל-מְלַאכְתּוֹ, אֲשֶׁר-בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים לַעֲשׂוֹת.
Mechon-Mamre side by side Hebrew and English

The hebrew word used here is "Shabath", but it does not mean "to rest". It means "to cease (doing something)", as in to come to an end, to terminate, to conclude, etc.
The Antonym is "to start".
So a better translation of this might be Young's Literal Translation (YLT)

and God completeth by the seventh day His work which He hath made, and ceaseth by the seventh day from all His work which He hath made. And God blesseth the seventh day, and sanctifieth it, for in it HE hath ceased from all His work which God had prepared for making. (Genesis 2:2-3 YLT)


καὶ συνετέλεσεν ὁ θεὸς ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἕκτῃ τὰ ἔργα αὐτοῦ ἃ ἐποίησεν καὶ κατέπαυσεν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἑβδόμῃ ἀπὸ πάντων τῶν ἔργων αὐτοῦ ὧν ἐποίησεν
καὶ ηὐλόγησεν ὁ θεὸς τὴν ἡμέραν τὴν ἑβδόμην καὶ ἡγίασεν αὐτήν ὅτι ἐν αὐτῇ κατέπαυσεν ἀπὸ πάντων τῶν ἔργων αὐτοῦ ὧν ἤρξατο ὁ θεὸς ποιῆσαι
Greek Septuagint (LXX) Genesis 2:2-3

The Greek language LXX translation correctly twice translated the Hebrew verb "shabath" in Genesis 2:2-3 into Greek as "katepausen", which means "to cease".
And now your question becomes "Why did God cease on the seventh day?"
Because creation was finished.

The 2 different words for "rested" are more clear with Hebrew transliteration (using BibleHub).

@GratefulDisciple Yeah, but the 2nd one isn't used here... :)

It foreshadows the death, atonement, and redemption of what God would do through the Messiah. His body would lay motionless (resting) in the tomb on the 7th day. Therefore the Jews are called to honor the cost of his death and basically rest doing nothing on that day/
